# How can I programmatically transfer data between 2 machines on different networks?

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming, data-transfer

I may have the client as a computer or mobile phone connected to WiFi, and the server is on a computer connected with Ethernet.
How can I transfer data such as images between them?

Code for client: -

```
import socket

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)  #
client.connect(('192.0.0.1', 1002))  # same ip address that server is bound to

file = open("an_image.jpg", 'rb') 
image_data = file.read(2048)

while image_data:
    client.send(image_data)
    image_data = file.read(2048)

file.close()
client.close()
```

Code for server: -

```
import socket

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(('', 1002))
server.listen()  # allows us to accept incoming connection

client_socket, client_address = server.accept()  


file = open('server_image.jpg', "wb")  
image_chunk = client_socket.recv(2048)  

while image_chunk: 
    file.write(image_chunk)
    image_chunk = client_socket.recv(2048)

file.close()
client_socket.close()
# ALWAYS CLOSE YOUR STREAMS
```

When I try to establish connection between machines as stated above, Client times out due to no response

Comment: Works as intended here. Are you sure it is not a networking problem? Your server do have 192.0,0,1 address? That address is accessible from your client? (eg, if it is a private network address, and your server is connected from your home wifi and the client from your phone 5G...)?

Comment: Also, 1012, on many machine, is a port reserved for system applications (on unix, a process need to be executed as root to bind on this port). So try with another port. 10012, for example. And try first by running both client and server on the same machine, just to test the code. If it works, then it is a networking problem (client cannot reach the server with address 192.0.0.1, and you need to solve that routing problem, independently from your code)

Comment: Yes, both client and server can connect if they are on the same machine.
The IP address and port I wrote was just a placeholder. I am trying to connect to server which is a computer with Linux OS and after I ran ifconfig, I got the inet address and attempted to connect.

Please let me know: How can I check if the server address is accessible by client?

Comment: If, when you put client on the same machine as server (rather than server on the same machine as client) it works that means that: 1. there is no specific problem with your code. 2. it is not a problem of port binding (using a reserved port, or a port already used. That is why i said "client on servers's machine rather than server on client's machine". The former working proves that server works ok with that port. The latter wouldn't prove that this port wouldn't a problem on the server machine)

Comment: So, back to problem: if it works with client on server's machine, but not when client is on its own machine, then, you know: server is not accessible by client.

Comment: It can either be because the address makes no sense to client (for example, address is a `192.168.*` address and client and server are not on the same subnet, so `192.168.x.x` does not mean the same thing to both.

Comment: Or it can be because this `192.168.x.x` is supposed to mean the same thing, but a route table somewhere is not configured correctly. Or it can be because a firewall in between is not allowing communication between those two machines (example, if client in on a DMZ for a webserver, and server in a non-dmz subnet. Then, server can talk to client, but client is not allowed to talk to server. Which, of course, is a problem for a client-server architecture). Or it can be because that specific port is blocked by the said firewall.

Comment: Or... anything actually. It could be some DPI firewall blocking things in between. It could be specific iptables rules on server side. It could be specific iptables rules on client side. It could be iptables rules on any router in between (aka firewall, since a router with iptables rules is pretty much the same as a firewall). Etc.

Comment: Since you said nothing of your network set up, hard to say. And even if you did, now that we know that this is not at all a programming problem, but a networking problem (how to configure the machines, and the network, so that the communication becomes possible), it also means that this is not really a question for [so]. Tho, obviously, there are some people here that know a thing or two about networking, myself included, it is offtopic here, and those people are more numerous on site where it is not off-topic. Like, maybe, [su] or [network enigneering].

Comment: But beware: you'll have to give more details on the networking. What is the iptables, and route tables of both server and client. How are they connected to each other (through a local network? Or only through internet?). Are the connected through the same ISP, the same "internet box"?  If this is a local network, what is its architecture? It there some firewall, VPN or things like that involved? etc, etc. If you just ask "my client cannot talk to my server, how can I solve that"... well you know how harsh people can be with beginners who ask question with not enough data.

Comment: Thank you @chrslg for the detailed explanation. 
It may be because my client is connected to Wifi and server is connected by Ethernet, but as you suggested I will investigate and come back with proper definition of the problem